# Virtualbox with i7-4790 one thread per virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-threading

I’m considering buying an Intel Core i7-4790, which has 4 cores and 8 threads.

With a 4 core, 8 thread CPU you should see 8 CPU available in the green slider area; see picture below. I set the slider to one per virtual machine. Afterwards I try to run 8 virtual machines at the same time.

Does this mean each virtual machine will use one thread or will each virtual machine use a full core?

Please have a look at this picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: Unless you pin VCPUs to CPUs (as seen by the OS), they can be executed on any physical CPU.

Comment: If you had 4 cores, and 4 VMs were using 1 core each, exclusively, then the world would implode since the host also needs CPU resources. ;)  Anyhow, each VM will use multiple threads, even if they're using only one Core, so your question (as-is) is a little off-kilter, and doesn't really show any research effort.

Comment: Related: [Quad Core host with hyper-threading, how many processors to configure in VirtualBox?](http://superuser.com/questions/668245/quad-core-host-with-hyper-threading-how-many-processors-to-configure-in-virtual?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Each CPU from this screenshot is **physically a thread** and for the guest OS it is presented as a **virtual core** (a single-threaded core, not an HT core).